# How can StringTemplate import directory be used?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I wrote a sample java file that is located in /src folder.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    STGroupFile StgFile=new STGroupFile("template.stg");
    StgFile.delimiterStartChar = '$';
    StgFile.delimiterStopChar = '$';
    ST webtemp=StgFile.getInstanceOf("test");
    webtemp.add("x","whyyy");
    System.out.println(webtemp.render());
  }
}
```

Also I have the file template.stg that is located in /src folder also

```
import "headers/header.stg" 
test(x) ::= << $included(x)$ >>
```

and the file header.stg that is located in /src/headers folder.

```
included(x) ::= << headers[$x$] >>
```

The result obviously is

```
headers[whyyy]
```

but if I try to import whole headers directory making the template.stg like that:

```
  import "headers" 
  test(x) ::= << $included(x)$ >>
```

- the included subtemplate can't be used...

The version of StringTemplate I use is the latest 4.0.5 and according to the link http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Differences+between+v3+and+v4 importing a directory is allowed.. I have even used / before and/or after / - relative/absolute paths and it doesn't work :( Any Help please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `$header/included(x)$`?

Comment: no - I will try it - but later - since I have removed StringTemplate from my project for a while. Thank you

Comment: That took some years - sorry about that - I have moved on with way different technologies as you can imagine but that answer worked back then :)